# How can I do it by forEach()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I already did some work with a search bar and it's working. Now I want to do it with `forEach()` or `filter()` instead of for loop with pure Javascript. Here is my HTML and JS code. Can anybody help me?

```js
function myFunction() {
  let input = document.getElementById('mySearch');
  let bind = input.value.toUpperCase();

  let ul = document.getElementById('myMenu');
  let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(bind) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = ''
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CSS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PHP</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Python</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">jQuery</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SQL</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Node.js</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how have you tried?

Comment: can I do it by  filter()  method?

Answer (score -1):

Either convert the collection of `li`s to an array, or use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a `NodeList`, which has the `forEach` method in newer browers:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let input = document.getElementById('mySearch');
  let bind = input.value.toUpperCase();

  document.querySelectorAll('#myMenu > li').forEach((li) => {
    if (li.textContent.includes(bind)) li.style.display = ''
    else li.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CSS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PHP</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Python</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">jQuery</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SQL</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Node.js</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you have an array-like collection and want to convert it into an array, you can use `Array.from`. Going off your original code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let input = document.getElementById('mySearch');
  let bind = input.value.toUpperCase();

  let ul = document.getElementById('myMenu');
  let lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  Array.from(lis).forEach((li) => {
    let a = li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(bind) > -1) {
      li.style.display = ''
    } else {
      li.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CSS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">PHP</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Python</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">jQuery</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SQL</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bootstrap</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Node.js</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can i do it by filter() method?

Comment: Not sensibly, because `filter` will only return the matched elements, whereas you need to change the style of *all* elements, not just the matching ones. (unless you went through the list twice, once to hide everything, and then once after a `.filter` to show the ones which match)

Answer (score -2):

There's no reason to use `filter` here as you're not trying to create an array, and there's no good reason to use `forEach` ever. If you are trying to simplify your code, use a `for … of` loop for hiding/showing the items:

```
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById('mySearch').value.toUpperCase();

  const items = document.getElementById('myMenu').getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (const li of items) {
    let a = li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    li.style.display = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(input) ? '' : 'none';
  }
}
```